# JDO app engine typesafe ancestor query

Tags: jdo, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I am using App Engine with DataNucleus JDO typesafe queries.  Is it possible to build type safe ancestor query using DataNucleus?  e.g. code from this app engine [link](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) refers to Organization as ancestor, what is the typesafe query in Java?

```
class Organization(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
class Person(db.Model):
    given_name = db.StringProperty()
    surname = db.StringProperty()
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        org = Organization.get_or_insert('ateam', name='ATeam')
        person = Person(parent=org)
        person.given_name='GI'
        person.surname='Joe'
        person.put()
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ", org)
        people = []
        for p in q.run():
            people.append({'given_name': p.given_name,
                        'surname': p.surname})
```

Comment: Typesafe query is simply a way of generating a particular JDOQL. Define what is the JDOQL that you want to use, and then people who don't use GAE can answer from a purely JDO perspective.

Comment: I want to build this query where org refers to ancestor in code sample referenced in question: ("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 ", org)

Comment: That's not JDOQL. "SELECT FROM Person WHERE field = :param" is JDOQL.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to find out if DataNucleus supports ancestor queries.  There is no documentation on this even though this is such an important piece of information to work with  Google App Engine Datastore.  But looks like this is not supported by DataNucleus.  It would be good to know if this type of query is supported even if it means it is not supported through type safety - at least this ancestor query functionality should be supported by DataNucleus.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: FWIW "DataNucleus" is nothing to do with GAE; the plugin "datanucleus-appengine" is Google's. DataNucleus is a separate project, and it knows nothing about GAE, just providing low level stuff. You can easily enough look at their issue tracker and see https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=14  that may or may not be what this "ancestor" thing is

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Datanucleus has a typesafe thing, which is inspired by `QueryDSL`.
You can see an example below, in Scala:

```scala
def querySingleRecords(jdbcDriver: String, jdbcUrl: String, username: String, password: String): Unit = {
  import javax.jdo.JDOHelper
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  import org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager

  val pu = props(jdbcDriver, jdbcUrl, username, password)

  val pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(pu.asJava)
  val pm  = pmf.getPersistenceManager.asInstanceOf[JDOPersistenceManager]

  import model.{Identifier, QIdentifier}
  import org.datanucleus.query.typesafe.TypesafeQuery

  val tq: TypesafeQuery[Identifier] = pm.newTypesafeQuery(classOf[Identifier])
  val q: QIdentifier = QIdentifier.candidate()

  def find(symbol: String): Unit = {
    val i: Identifier =
      tq
        .filter(q.symbol.eq(symbol))
        .executeUnique()
        .asInstanceOf[Identifier]
    assert(symbol == i.symbol, s""""%s" not equal to "%s"""".format(symbol, i.symbol))

    if(debug) {
      println("%s -> %d".format(i.symbol, i.fk))
    }
  }

  find("PETR4.SA")
  find("ACIM")
  find("ZVV")
  find("AAIT")
  find("ZUMZ")
  find("AAAIF.OB")
  find("ZYXI.OB")
  find("AALC34.SA")
  find("ZURI9.SA")
}
```

For a complete example using that, inclusing a big `build.sbt` file which does all the magic of generating metaclassea and running the bytecode enhancer, please have a look at

http://github.com/frgomes/poc-scala-datanucleus